# Changing a value to that of a checked radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

I have these radio buttons on a page and a button to go to the next page. (Called 'Doorgaan'). In the next page, I have this h2 with id "CatNaam" of which I want the value [CATEGORIENAAM] to be changed into the value of the checked radio button.
How do I do this?

```
    <div data-role="page" id="beoordelen" data-theme="a">

        <div data-role="header">
            <h1>Beoordelen</h1>
            <a class="ui-btn-left" data-theme="a" data-rel="back">Vorige</a>
        </div><!-- /header -->

        <div data-role="content" data-theme="a">    
            <h2>Kies categorie</h2>
            <form id="oordeelKeuze" method="get">
                   <p>      
                      <input type = "radio" name = "categorie-oordeel" id = "goedkoop-bier" value = "Goedkoop bier" checked = "checked" />
                      <label for = "goedkoop-bier">Goedkoop bier</label>
                   </p><p>                    
                      <input type = "radio" name = "categorie-oordeel" id = "muziek" value = "Muziek" />
                      <label for = "muziek">Muziek</label>
                    </p><p>      
                      <input type = "radio" name = "categorie-oordeel" id = "gezelligheid" value = "Gezelligheid" />
                      <label for = "gezelligheid">Gezelligheid</label>
                    </p>   
            </form>
            <p><a href="#beoordelen2" data-direction="reverse" data-role="button" data-theme="b">Doorgaan</a></p>   

        </div><!-- /content -->


    </div><!-- /beoordelen -->

    <!-- Start of fifth page: #beoordelen2 -->
    <div data-role="page" id="beoordelen2" data-theme="a">

        <div data-role="header">
            <h1>Beoordelen</h1>
            <a class="ui-btn-left" data-theme="a" data-rel="back">Vorige</a>
        </div><!-- /header -->

        <div data-role="content" data-theme="a">    
            <h2>Geef cijfer voor</h2>
            <h2 id="CatNaam">[CATEGORIENAAM]</h2>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: the html code you have provided have both the divs in same page.. is it the same ??

Comment: Yes, it's a multipage application, just like this one: http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/multipage-template.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using jQuery, give your button (Doorgaan) an id:

```
 <p><a href="#beoordelen2" data-direction="reverse" data-role="button" data-theme="b" id="buttonID">Doorgaan</a></p>   //buttonID in this case
```

and on your button (Doorgaan) on click add this:

```
$('#buttonID').click(function(){
   var selectedRadio= $("input[type='radio'][name='categorie-oordeel']:checked").val();
  $('#CatNaam').text(selectedRadio);
})
```

Here is the working example in a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/F5brz/

Comment: Wooohooo! bipen, you rock! I've been staring at this for a day and now finally it's working! :D

Answer (score 0):

If you use jQuery, you can do it like this:

```
var val = $('input[name="categorie-oordeel"]:checked').val();
$('#CatNaam').text(val);
```

Comment: Thanks. You're my hero. The value is finally changing to the checked radio button. The only problem I have now, is that the button that is linking to the next page, isn't saving the radio button that gets checked. So I only see the text that is checked by default, which is "Goedkoop bier" in this case. Do you know how I get the new checked value saved? At this moment, the button just links to the next page. 
<a href="#beoordelen2" data-direction="reverse" data-role="button" data-theme="b">Doorgaan</a>